# Poner un texto bajo un ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio

como sería para hacer algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Hola @MarioAzcVei, para que entiendas el funcionamiento de esta web deberías leer el [tour] del sitio. Además, para que veas como realizar una pregunta de calidad y que sea bien aceptada por los participantes lee [ask], así si realizas una buena pregunta se te ayudará con las dudas que tengas.

Comment: Mario, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para futuras preguntas (y también para esta), considera que aquí [un fragmento de código en texto vale más que mil imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2990/29967). Quiere decir que es más útil poner el código XML de tu `ImageView` y de tu `TextView`, que esta captura de pantalla. No obstante, para lograrlo, podría ser colocando esto en el `TextView`: **`android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"`**, aquí se supone que la `imageView` que muestras tiene el id: `imageView`, si no es así pones su id real.

Comment: Has realizado algo Mario?

Comment: Es lo que quiero saber como se hace, el XML, la imagen es de google.